# how to set match parent,wrap content,horizontal scroll for an image

Tags: android, html, css, cordova

i would like to know about these features to implement it in an html file in eclipse for Phonegap android.

**MATCH PARENT / WRAP CONTENT**

I did not know how to give MATCH PARENT / WRAP CONTENT, so i gave as the following 2 ways

```
<div id="container" style="width:315px height:150px">
```

OR WHEN I GIVE

```
<div id="container" >
```

the problem i am facing is when i don't give any width..this element is an image,it goes till the measurement ends / the maximum limit.

**SPACE BETWEEN THE DIV ELEMENTS AND SPACE VISIBLE IN THE LEFT AND THE TOP OF EACH ELEMENT**

WHEN I GIVE THE FOLLOWING,THERE IS A GAP TO THE LEFT AND TOP OF THE VIEW

```
<div id="wrapper" style="width: 100%; float: left; margin: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-top: 0px;">
```

**HORIZONTAL SCROLL VIEW**

FOR **horizontal scroll view** i gave

```
                     div#main
        {  //background-image:url('img/image1.png');
           position:absolute;
           top:40%;
           margin-top:-50px;
        }
```

when we scroll the image,the backgrounds too scrolls...But, whereas i want the image alone to scroll bot the background...

**WHAT SHOULD I DO?**

so,please help me for setting **MATCH PARENT,WRAP CONTENT,AND HORIZONTAL SCROLL VIEW** IN HTML()PREFERABLY??

**edit:code after suggesrtions**

```
<div id="wrapper" style="width: 100%; float: left;padding:0px; margin:0px;">
        <div id="container" style="padding:0px; margin:0px;">
        
        <div id="head" style="background-image:url(mdpi/purple_navigation.png);"></div>
        <h1 style=" margin-left:0px; margin-top:0px;  padding:0px; margin:0px;"> ABC</h1></div>
    
        <div id="wrapper" style="padding:0px; margin:0px;">
        <div id="images"  style="padding:0px; margin:0px;">
        <marquee direction="left" behavior="alternate" scrolldelay="3" width="100% padding:0px; margin:0px;"><img src="mdpi/banner1.png"/><img src="mdpi/banner2.png"/><img src="mdpi/banner3.png"/><img src="mdpi/banner4.png"/><img src="mdpi/banner5.png"/></marquee> 
        </div>
                
        
        <div id="title" style="padding:0px; margin:0px;"><h1>title</h1></div>
        <div id="desc" style="padding:0px; margin:0px;"><p>description </p></div>
        </div>
            
</div>

</body>
```

**before changes**
[image: before changes]

**after changes**
[image: after changes]

### **HOW SHOULD I BRING THAT TEXT AT HEADER(ABC/TITLE) TO THE CENTER?**

Comment: Can you try to recreate this in (http://jsfiddle.net/) to make it a bit easier to understand what you want to achieve. And instead of using `padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-top: 0px;`, you can use `padding:0px;`

Comment: YUP,i have done it there..but my images which i use as background is not visible...

Comment: If you're using an external stylesheet, where is your stylesheet located? Is it located in the root folder? or is it located in a seperate folder?

Comment: No Sir, i dont use an external style sheet i use inline CSS (if i am not wrong)..i give the style command while giving the html tag itself.

Comment: Ok. Can you place the link here to your created jsfiddle so that I can see what you have so far? It would make it a bit easier to locate your problem

Comment: Phillip-juan sir, please find it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vTSmt/)

Comment: Here's what I have so far: (http://jsfiddle.net/vTSmt/9/) Any other issues here?

Comment: yeah,the issue is there too much of gap between these text and images

Comment: If you have a look here: (http://jsfiddle.net/vTSmt/19/), you will see that when changing the `h1` tags to `span` and setting the `font-size` you can achieve the same result, but the `h1` tags added the extra padding. If you want to keep the `h1` tags, you can try to manipulate the `h1` tags using `margin:0px` like here: (http://jsfiddle.net/vTSmt/22/). Hope this helps

Comment: thank you, Phillip-juan sir, thank you.90% of my problem solved...10% remaining.

Comment: Happy to help. What is your remaining issues?

Comment: changes made in the post...the title and description are still the apart,not like the title and the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To center the text for the header, all you have to do is to add `text-align:center;` to that div.

Also, I have changed a couple of things in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vTSmt/36/).

Is this the result you want, just without the background colors?

The changes I made was that I moved the `#description` `div` and added styles to some of the other divs.

> Let me know if you have any other issues or if this isn't working for
>   you.

***Hope this is satisfactory :)***

Comment: yup, i want it without the background colors..just trying to implement it for the title and description.thank you for the help..will try to excute it and let you know the result.

Comment: Ok, I only added the colors so that it's clearly visible that there are no spaces.